# LZ4 is not fast compared to deflater compressing string

Tags: java, compression, lz4

I tried to use LZ4 compression to compress a string object.But the result are not in favour to LZ4
Here is the program i tried

```
public class CompressionDemo {

    public static byte[] compressGZIP(String data) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime ();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
        gzip.write(data.getBytes());
        gzip.close();
        byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.close();
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-start);
        return compressed;
    }

    public static byte[] compressLZ4(String data) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime ();
        LZ4Factory factory = LZ4Factory.fastestJavaInstance();
        LZ4Compressor compressor = factory.highCompressor();
        byte[] result = compressor.compress(data.getBytes());
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-start);
        return result;

    }

    public static byte[] compressDeflater(String stringToCompress) {
        long start = System.nanoTime ();
        byte[] returnValues = null;
        try {
            Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
            deflater.setInput(stringToCompress.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            deflater.finish();
            byte[] bytesCompressed = new byte[Short.MAX_VALUE];
            int numberOfBytesAfterCompression = deflater.deflate(bytesCompressed);
            returnValues = new byte[numberOfBytesAfterCompression];
            System.arraycopy(bytesCompressed, 0, returnValues, 0, numberOfBytesAfterCompression);
        } catch (Exception uee) {
            uee.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-start);
        return returnValues;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
        System.out
                .println("..it’s usually most beneficial to compress anyway, and determine which payload (the compressed or the uncompressed one) has the smallest size and include a small token to indicate whether decompression is required."
                        .getBytes().length);
        byte[] arr = compressLZ4("..it’s usually most beneficial to compress anyway, and determine which payload (the compressed or the uncompressed one) has the smallest size and include a small token to indicate whether decompression is required.");
        System.out.println(arr.length);
    }
}
```

[image]
I have collected statics as above.But LZ4 is not that fast as stated
Please let me where am i doing wrong.

Comment: **1)** If you really want to compare the compression speed you should have a look on [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) otherwise your results are worth nothing. **2)** You should only compare the compression execution itself. As for example creating the LZ4 factory is more time expensive then a `new Defalter(int)` and for a small inputs this might have a bad impact on the measured total time.

Answer (score 4):

Your results are meaningless because the size before compression is too small. You are trying to measure the compression of a few thousand bytes at speeds over 100MB/s. The measurement is lost in the time taken by the JVM to warm up. Try again with an input file of several MBs. You should get numbers in line with my LZ4 implementation here: https://github.com/flanglet/kanzi/wiki/Compression-examples.